# React ChartJS Donut Chart Align Rings

Tags: reactjs, donut-chart, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to have multiple rings in my donut chart, where each ring going out is more divided.

For example, if we have a list of hours worked, I want to group it by two things, user, then by job. I would want the inner ring to be a ring divided by user. Then I would want the outer ring to be by user-job, where each wedge of the inner circle has all the outer circle pieces match up so that the sub-divisions line up inside the wedge.

Here is a visual that I hope can help.
The purple, blue, dark blue section are sub-groups of the red group. Same idea applies to the green/yellow/light green sub-groups and the orange group.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find example of a stacked doughnut chart.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
    <canvas id="chart-area" width="500" height="500" />
</div>
<script>
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var randomColorFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
};

var config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
            ],
                backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#4D5360",
            ],
        }, {
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
            ],
                backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#4D5360",
            ],
        }, {
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
            ],
                backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#4D5360",
            ],
        }],
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Green",
            "Yellow",
            "Grey",
            "Dark Grey"
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
</script>
```

You know would need to provide the data so as to have your explained case of use and for the subdivisions to fit in as you explained.